# IIS 6.0 SSL handshake error

Tags: iis, ssl, openssl

Hi all I installed a trusted certificate in an IIS 6.0 server. I have the port 443 opened in the firewall and I verified the server is listening on that port. However when verifying using openssl I get the following error

```
$ openssl s_client -connect HOST:443 -debug -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x1001182b0 [0x10080a600] (130 bytes => 130 (0x82))
0000 - 80 80 01 03 01 00 57 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   ......W... ..9..
0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 00 00 9a 00 00 99 00   ..3..2../.......
0030 - 00 96 03 00 80 00 00 05-00 00 04 01 00 80 00 00   ................
0040 - 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06-00 40 00 00 14 00 00 11   .........@......
0050 - 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00-80 00 00 03 02 00 80 00   ................
0060 - 00 ff fc cd 35 31 42 09-11 be d0 ab 79 27 30 cb   ....51B.....y'0.
0070 - 83 ce 16 ea 39 ab 14 cd-3b 2e ca 9e c9 70 05 46   ....9...;....p.F
0080 - 50 5b                                             P[
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0x1001182b0 [0x10080fc00] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
19973:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.1/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:
```

I googled the error but only had a clue that maybe SSL v3.0 was required but when tried with -ssl3 option had the same output

Any thoughts?

Thanks
V

Comment: What kind of ssl cert is it?  Which CA did it come from?

Comment: I have a very similar problem with an Thawte SSL123 cert at the moment. Interesstingly in my case the certificate works fine in Firefox on Windows XP but has equal problems on a OSX client. I do not think it has to do with the version of SSL / TLS. Could you try the command without -debug. What does https://ssl-tools.verisign.com/#certChecker tell you?

Comment: I posted a separate question on my issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/437561/ssl-connection-error-during-handshake-on-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Could you try with openssl s_client -debug -msg -state -status -showcerts -connect <host>:443 and verify that you have not disabled SSLv2 or SSLv3 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/187498) as these have been disabled recently on a lot of systems due to security problems. Are you using anything in between the client and the host that might be performing some inspection.. like a hardware firewall?

Answer (score 0):

I get that you already tried ssl3 and you asked the question a long time ago, but in case it helps someone else!

Try ssl2, ssl3 and tls1 using one of the static openssl binaries which come with [testssl](https://testssl.sh/). These support more protocols and ciphers than the standard openssl.

If that doesn't work, (or even if it does!) you can also run testssl against the server with one of those binaries:

```
testssl --openssl=./path_to_openssl_static_binaries
```