# SSL connection error during handshake on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

**Update:** Issue solved by re-rolling the certificate.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server that runs a HTTPS Tunneling service. The software uses a certificate that is provided via the Windows certificate store. The certificate is located in the local computer private certificates. It supports server and client authentication with signing and keyencipherment.

## Cert chain

The certificate chain looks fine. It's a Thawte SSL123 certificate.

- Thawte Premium Server CA (SHA1) [‎e0 ab 05 94 20 72 54 93 05 60 62 02 36 70 f7 cd 2e fc 66 66]

  - thawte Primary Root CA [‎1f a4 90 d1 d4 95 79 42 cd 23 54 5f 6e 82 3d 00 00 79 6e a2]

    - Thawte DV SSL CA [3c a9 58 f3 e7 d6 83 7e 1c 1a cf 8b 0f 6a 2e 6d 48 7d 67 62]

      - Server certificate

## Issues

Most browsers accept the certificate without any warning. But IE 7 on Windows XP SP3 and Opera 12 on OSX just report an connection error. Opera complains:

```
Secure connection: fatal error (552)
https://www.example.com/
Opera was not able to connect to the server, because the server does not communicate via any secure protocol known to Opera.
```

A connection test using `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -state` says:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
52471:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.1/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:
```

`ssldump -aAHd host www.example.com` during `curl https://www.example.com/` reports:

```
New TCP connection #1: localhost(53302) <-> www.example.com(443)
1 1  0.0235 (0.0235)  C>SV3.1(117)  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.1 
        random[32]=
          50 77 56 29 e8 23 82 3b 7f e0 ae 2d c1 31 cb ac 
          38 01 31 85 4f 91 39 c1 04 32 a6 68 25 cd a0 c1 
        cipher suites
        Unknown value 0x39
        Unknown value 0x38
        Unknown value 0x35
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x33
        Unknown value 0x32
        Unknown value 0x2f
        Unknown value 0x9a
        Unknown value 0x99
        Unknown value 0x96
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        Unknown value 0xff
        compression methods
                unknown value
                  NULL
1    0.0479 (0.0243)  S>C  TCP FIN
1    0.0481 (0.0002)  C>S  TCP FIN
```

Thawte provides two Java based SSL Checkers. The [Legacy Thawte SSL Certificate Installation Checker](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO9555) and the [sslToolBox](https://ssl-tools.verisign.com/#certChecker). Both validate the certificate under Windows XP but report connection errors under OSX and Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: There is a similar question by victor-hugo: http://serverfault.com/questions/317968/iis-6-0-ssl-handshake-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out what the issue was, but solved it via re-enrolling a new certificate. This Time using the IIS Manager instead of doing it manually using the Windows Certificate Manager.

So my only tip would be to **start from scratch** if things are too strange and searching for an error takes more time than just starting over.